# leaving the US without US passport

Tags: usa

Does anyone has recent experience for dual citizen leaving the US with foreign passport? I have to leave and this passport thing takes forever

Comment: You don't need a passport to leave the US. Coming back though is am entirely different problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The US does not have exit immigration checks (no matter if you leave by land, sea, or air). So generally nothing will stop you from leaving.